# git diff - adding edits to (un)committed versions

Tags: github, git-diff

This command below:

$git diff 567f704d31101aa9d

Being "567f704d31101aa9d" the name of a version of the file I created, is this command going to compare this version with the latest version (*committed or not*) or with the last *committed* version?